# Appending to list with loop

Tags: python, list, loops

i'm confused with this piece of python. From my understanding it should only do the loop once as there is only one element in the list however it seems to continuously loop and I have no idea why. I know how to get it working to do what I want but i'm just confused as to why this didn't work to begin with. Thanks

```
y=["hello"]
for n in y:
    y.append("e")
```

Comment: Your loop would end when you get to the end of the list `y`. You don't get to the end of the list because you keep adding extra stuff onto it. It's better not to alter something while you're iterating through it.

Comment: You're changing the length of the list while iterating over it - this is a bad idea. See http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=y%3D%5B%22hello%22%5D%0Afor%20n%20in%20y%3A%0A%20%20%20%20y.append(%22e%22%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false for a visualisation

Comment: Instead you can save the updates in another list

Comment: Ye i'm sorry I just realised this almost instantly after posting after being confused and googling for about 45 minutes. Thanks I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding new elements to `y` with each iteration of the loop. On the first iteration, it will see `'hello'` and then append an `'e'`. On the second iteration, it sees that `'e'` and appends another, then on the third it sees that one, and so on. Similar problems occur if you try to delete, rather than append, elements to a list you're iterating over. If you want to avoid this, iterate over a copy:

```
>>> y = ["hello"]
>>> for n in y[:]:
...     y.append("e")
...
>>> y
['hello', 'e']
```

Comment: I just realised why. Its because I'm continually adding to the list so theres always one more element in the list thus the infinite loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending some data on the same list you're parsing. At the end of each iteration new elements have been added ("e"), that's why you made an infinite loop.

> ```
> ["hello"] # 1 element, "e" will be added once
> ["hello", "e"] # 2 elements, "e" will be added twice
> ["hello", "e", "e", "e"] # 4 elements, "e" will be added 4 times
> ...
> ```